# Android Login: Login Failed even with correct input?

Tags: android, button, authentication

So I've been trying to do this simple login app without database. Login will be successful if the input is the same with the defined functions.

Button is functioning well but I can't login even if I input the correct values!

Here are the codes

Declaration

```
String id ="id";
String pw ="pw";
```

If else

```
userET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
                  passwordET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

              loginBT = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
              loginBT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                          try {
                                if(userET.equals(id)
                                            && passwordET.equals(
                                                        pw)) {
                                      Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                                                  "login passed!!",
                                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

                                      //user = userET.getText();

                                      startActivity(new Intent("MainActivity"));

                                } else {
                                      Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                                                  "login failed!!",
                                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                    }
              });
        } 

        }
```

thank you in advance

UPDATE: Sorry I should've posted a new question my previous question was about the button this was my second question I just edited it because right after I posted the previous one I immediately realized what's wrong and fixed it. I didn't knew some people was able to answer back quickly thanks to those people. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do this:

```
username = userET.getText().toString();
password = passwordET.getText().toString();
```

before:

```
if(username.equals(id) && password.equals(pw)) {
```

because the values of username and password are null.

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer! but right when I posted my question I was able to fix it right away I'm sorry but I got another problem maybe you could help me out?

Comment: @user3508677 I could try

Comment: `userET.equals(id)` don't do it

Comment: `id.equal(userET.getText().toString())`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        if(username.equals(id) && password.equals(pw))
            [...]
```

And where are you taking the values of `username` and `password` from?

**You have to read them from your text fields before checking them!**

```
username = userET.getText().toString();
password = passwordET.getText().toString();
```

**UPDATE:**

you do now compare the TextViews with the id/pw. Don't do this. You want to compare the Text from the TextViews, not the TextViews themselves:

```
String InputUsername = userET.getText()
String InputPassword = passwordET.getText()
```

And then compare those values with the predefined ones.

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer! but right when I posted my question I was able to fix it right away I'm sorry but I got another problem maybe you could help me out?

Comment: I will try, ask it in another question :) But you should marked this question as answered then, because you need no more answer ;)

Comment: I kinda made a mistake I just edited the whole post instead on making a new one because I was able to get it working right after a posted it. Sorry!

Comment: I'm still having trouble I still can't log in with the correct values. I edited my posts showing the details thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

add this before compare

```
username = userET.getText().toString();
password = passwordET.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned values to variables 'username' and 'password'. Add this:

```
username = userET.getText().toString();
password = passwordET.getText().toString();
```

before the try/catch blocks.